# Math Stack Exchange swag ideas

Tags: discussion, community

Recently we started the process of designing and ordering swag for our SE communities top users (high rep users on the [first 2 pages](https://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all) of all time).

You can see some examples of the items and designs at [GIS.se](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/503/gis-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users), [Gaming.se](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2288/gaming-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users) or [Programmers.se](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/programmers-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users).

So far we've only done T-shirts and Stickers for customized designs. Before I get started on the swag design for our Math.se community, do you prefer t-shirt and stickers, or are there other type of items you'd like to have instead? coffee mugs? or potentially [another item](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/all)?

[image: math.se]

As for the design, I typically use site's logo and url, to keep it simple. If you have any suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: From the link you gave, my preference would be (with most likely to use first): nalgene bottle, mug, sharpies, pens, stickers.

Comment: Oh, and as to the design, I think the normal header (the icon and "MATHEMATICS") big, with the URL smaller below might look better than the icon followed by the URL in all caps.

Comment: @Issac I agree. the full url in that size is too big.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what t-shirt colors are being considered? I would be partial to light grey, but I'd probably get whatever ends up being offered.

Comment: @Zev given the site is on a white background, I think a white t-shirt compliments the graphic color the most(red/dark blue on white).

Comment: @Jin: That's perfect. I go for  T-Shirts and Pens.

Comment: @Jin: I would rather have a coffee mug, pen or writing pad.  Is that for top users only?

Comment: @Américo it's for the top users of the [first 2 pages](http://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all)(sorted by All). But eventually we plan to put all the items available on our [company store](http://shop.stackexchange.com/) so people can purchase them if they like.

Comment: @Jin: Thanks! So if I stay within those 1st 2 pages I will get one. But I live in Portugal.

Comment: @Américo we will ship it globally.

Comment: @Jin: I see. Thanks!

Comment: @Jin: When will the shirt design be put up?

Comment: This is a very nice idea! Is this still going to happen? Has a design been decided yet?

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback! We're putting together the final set of items, expect an announcement and sign-up sheet to be posted here on meta shortly.

Comment: Is the [cute panda](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/all) still for sale?

Answer (score 14):

Swag is pretty nice, I think that *useful* swag is better.

For the mathematician case, I can suggest the coffee mug (as Erdos' said "a mathematician is a machine turning coffee into theorems") and even better a writing pad... I could sure use a new one, and as Isaac suggests in the comments pens and such. Preferably black, but blue works out just as well.

As for a shirt, I am not sure if I would wear one.

**Edit:** Since Willie is surprised I suggested some sort of a tool for drugs (well, caffeine... but still a psychoactive drug!), I will suggest things that will be useful *to me* in the same spirit: low-ball glasses and coasters.

On the same spirit, but not as useful to me (as I am not smoking), ashtrays and cigarette boxes, as well lighters and matches.

(All the addition is meant to be tongue in cheek, but I will gladly sit and drink scotch from a math.SE low ball, on a math.SE coaster!)

**Edit II:** Reviewing the current swag, I think that it is more than just what sort of swag, but also what should be printed on it.

I would enjoy a coffee mug with the quote by Erdos, or some theorem about the consistency of happiness and the contents of the mug (e.g. if it has hard liquor)

For a lowball and other tumblers, this should be more sophisticated.

As per shirts, writing pads and cardboard blocks to write on, there we can put proofs, cheatsheets for math and so on.

Comment: @Asaf: I'm surprised you suggested the coffee mug (as opposed to the tumbler). `:-)`

Comment: In any case, I would agree that coffee mug is the best (though shipping-wise it could be a pain maybe?). Walking around the department with a math.SE mug in hand is bound to also be good advertisement for the site!

Comment: @Willie: I'm not clear about why you are surprised, it's not like I have a use for a beer mug :). Also, a writing pad is the best.

Comment: @Asaf: beer mug? When I said tumbler, I meant [tumbler](http://www.wineware.co.uk/Whisky-Glass-1.htm). (Which perfectly agrees with your clarification; save I didn't know you like it on the rocks.) I disagree with writing pads: a mug is forever (or at least until you break it a few years down); a writing pad is for, what, about 4 weeks?

Comment: 2x +1 @Willie I thought the same, but I resisted the temptation...

Comment: @Willie: Tumblers are not my style, low balls allow better access to the scotch. Also, it scorching hot during the summer, and scotch on the rocks is perfect to cool down!

Comment: @Willie and Asaf: hilarious! I laughed out loud reading Asaf's post, and burst out laughing at the comments, too.   C8

Answer (score 10):

I agree with Isaac. The full url in that size is too big.

Here are some of the stuff which came to my mind

- T-shirts
- Backpack
- Coffee mug
- Stickers
- Pen and Writing pad

And thanks to everyone @ SE

Answer (score -5):

As somebody who will never make it to those illustrious two pages, I am perhaps not qualified to comment.  But a nice mug might lean on Alfréd Rényi's quote "A mathematician is a device for turning coffee into theorems"

Comment: Illustrious or not, you're five years too late.

Comment: Ouch.....5 years too late.....