# gifts after some reputation threshold

Tags: discussion

I got to know that stackoverflow gives gifts after 100k reputation, and then I wondered if this community did the same. Apparently this was once planned [Math Stack Exchange swag ideas](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2376/math-stack-exchange-swag-ideas), but I'm not sure if it got implemented. Does someone knows what happened?

Stackoverflow gifts: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321681/do-users-still-get-the-package-when-their-rep-reaches-100k

Comment: The main site used to give them out. I got some when I passed 100k, but then [Iwas the first user on the network outside of Stackoverflow to pass that threshold](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3570/742). Don't know if they still do.

Comment: I got some swag several years ago. It was based on points, but I don't remember what the threshhold was. I was hoping it would be an annual thing, but so far as I know it has never been repeated.

Comment: That's very nice. May I ask what did you receive?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=Swag and sort by Newest.

Comment: In 2012 (or 2013?) they gave a coffee mug and a T-shirt with Math. SE logo on them to (IIRC) top 30 rep holders.

Comment: I got  a branded mug, some stickers, and some branded pends, if I recall correctly.